# I was going through a spring boot tutorial on trying to make a sign up and sign in page and now im locked out

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am currently trying to make an index page go to a sign up page and sign in page, however I have somehow locked myself out and I am unsure how I've done it. right now my mvccontroller links me to the index page but when I go to localhost:8080 it goes to a login screen asking for a username and password which I haven't created yet. I'm pretty sure its the default login screen for springboot but I don't know how to get rid of it and I don't want it to be the first thing that comes up when you go to local host. What would I have done to get this to come up as in the tutorial they just get a nice index page.

https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/user-registration-and-login-tutorial

this is the tutorial and I am on step 5 and as you can see they have their own index page with hyperlinks but mine just goes to the default login page straight away.

Any help is appreciated thanks!